Computing 2nd polar moment of area for complex compound profile
I am trying to conduct a torsional analysis of several specific shafts.
The section profile of the shafts are round with an arbitrary number of evenly spaced circular cutouts (in this case 4) around its perimeter where the center of the cutouts land directly on the diameter of the main shaft. See below:

This is basically the compounding of circular profiles like the image below:

My question is how would I compute this second polar moment of area? I know it cant be as simple as just subtracting 4 smaller circles from a larger circle because the smaller circles only partially intersect, and they are also located off the axis of rotation. I also need to compute this for 2 and 3 circle cutouts that are evenly spaced but I assume the formula will be very similar once I understand how to do it for this shape.
Thank you for your time.

Exact* solution
The intersection of the big and small circle can be divided into into 2 areas (circle segments) using a chord. 1/8 of the section with symmetric halves of the segments is on the following figure:

Second polar moment of circle segment
Polar moment of a segment with radius $R$ and half-angle $\varphi_x$ is:
$$I_{p,s}(R, \varphi_x) = 2\cdot\int\limits_{0}^{\varphi_x}\int\limits_{R\cdot \cos(\varphi_x)/\cos(\varphi)}^{R} \rho^3 d\rho d\varphi
= \frac{R^4}{2} \cdot\int\limits_{0}^{\varphi_x} 1-\frac{\cos(\varphi_x)}{\cos(\varphi)} d\varphi$$
Complicated integral (from wolfram alpha)
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(\varphi)} d\varphi = \ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\right) - \ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\right) + \text{constant}$$
The exact solution is:
$$I_{p,s}(R, \varphi_x) = \frac{R^4}{2} \cdot\left(\varphi_x-\cos(\phi_x)\cdot\left(\ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right)}\right)
- \ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(0\right) + \cos\left(0\right)}{\cos\left(0\right) - \sin\left(0\right)}\right)\right)\right)$$
$$I_{p,s}(R, \varphi_x) = \frac{R^4}{2} \cdot\left(\varphi_x-\cos(\phi_x)\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\varphi_x}{2}\right)}\right)\right)$$
Intersection angles defining the segments
Angle at the intersection from the origin of the big circle $\varphi_x$
$$\varphi_x = 2\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)$$
Angle at the itersection from the origin of the small circle $\vartheta_x$
$$\vartheta_x = \arcsin\left(\frac{R\cdot \sin\left(\varphi_x\right)}{r}\right)$$
Final $I_p$ calculation
So you can caclulate $I_p$ for full circle and then subtract $I_{p,sR}$ and $I_{p,sr}$ from it. For the second one, you will need the area $A$ and the center of mass $c$ of the segment, to make similar shift like in Kamran's answer. These are based on wiki:

centroid
$$c = \frac{4r\sin^3(\vartheta_x)}{3\cdot (2\vartheta_x-\sin(2\vartheta_x))}$$
area
$$A = \frac{r^2}{2}\cdot (2\vartheta_x-\sin(2\vartheta_x))$$

And finally, the polar moment of your section should be:
$$I_p = \frac{\pi R^4}{2}-4\cdot\left(I_{p,s}(R, \varphi_x) + I_{p,s}(r, \vartheta_x)+A\cdot (R-c)^2\right)$$
Comparison with Kamran's approach
I made a comparison with Kamran approach and I think it is interesting. On the $x$ axis, there is the ratio of small/big circle radii $r/R$ and on $y$ axis, there is the second polar moment of the section divide by second polar moment of full circle with radius $R$. The green vertical line represents a situation where the neighbouring small circles would touch, so it is the upper $r/R$ limit of such section and both calculations.

*Why it is not really exact
Presented formula is based on $I_p = \iint\limits_\Gamma r^2 dA$, which assumes the section remains in plane during twisting. This is however not true in general as was discovered by Saint-Venant. Figure in this article comes from his analysis of torsion of beam with elliptical section.
If you need something more accurate than this, you may need to use numeric simulation like FEA or experiments.

Thank you Tomas for this extensive analysis. Just to be sure, are both the phi symbols you use in Ip,s(R,φx) equation identical? I notice there are two styles used but cannot tell if they represent the same thing.

$I_{p,s}(R, \varphi_x)$ is supposed to be a general function that computes second polar moment of area of a segment of the circle with radius $R$ and half angle $\varphi_x$ with respect to that circle center. It is once used for the big circle, so $R=R$ and $\varphi_x=\varphi_x$, but then it is also used for the small circle, where $R=r$ and $\varphi_x=\vartheta_x$ and this one has to be shifted using the $A\cdot (R-c)^2$ trick.

if $ \ r<<R\ $  we can approximate
$\text{the area of the cut-off lens as half the area of the small circle}$:
Then the approximate answer is
$$ J_{circle} = \frac{\pi R^4}{2}$$
$$J_{small circle/2} = \frac{\pi r^4}{4}$$

J =2nd polar moment of inertia

Then using the parallel axis Theorem:
$$ J_{\text{small circle/2, shifted}} = J_{\text{small circle/2}} + \text{Area} \ {\text{small circle/2}} \times (R-4r/3π )^2 $$
$$(R-4r/3π) = \text{distance between the lens CG and circle center} $$
$$J_{total}= J_{circle}- 4 J_{\text{small circle/2, shifted}}$$

Thank you Kamran.
How much smaller do you think r should be than R to make this assumption? In my case little r is about 1/2 of R meaning most of the large diameter circle is actually “missing”.

@thisissparzo, In your case, I would estimate that we are off by no more than 3-4%. Remember the narrow slivers on the right and left sides of small circles that would be added if the big circle was much larger; they have little effect on the second polar moment. J= r^2 dA increases as the cross section becomes more rounded, and decreases when the section is narrow.
